# Как показать json данные подгруженные ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, slim

при добавление в бд поста через ajax, отправляю этот пост в json формате, все приходит, но я не могу понять как в div.container_box показать его.
В контроллере выводятся все посты из бд, но если type = xhr то подгружает добавленный пост

```
public function all_post(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
{
    $stmt = $this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `post`");
    $posts = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($request->isXhr()) {
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(end($posts))); // последний ключ из БД
        return $response->withHeader('Content-type',
            'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    }

    return $this->view->render($response, 'admins/admin.posts.twig',
        [
            'posts' => $posts
        ]);
}
```

js

```
// выше идет сохранение поста в БД
$(document).on('click','#add_post_popup', function () {

    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=file],input[type=text], 
        textarea").val("");

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "http://slim.com/spirits/panel/post",
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d) {
           $('.wrapper').append(JSON.stringify(d)) // 

            // $('.wrapper').load("http://slim.com/spirits/panel/post .container_box");
        }
    });
```

});

twig

```
<div class="wrapper">

        {%for post in posts%}
            <div class="container_box">
                {{post.id}}
                {{post.name}}
                {{post.link}}
            </div>

        {%endfor%}
</div>
```

Как мне поместить его в div.container_box и показать как два верхних
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
$('.wrapper').append(JSON.stringify(d))
```

Сделайте что-то вроде этого:

```
var item = $('<div class="container-box"></div>');
item.text( 'id - ' + d.id + ' name - ' + d.name + ' alias - ' + d.link );
$('.wrapper').append( item );
```

Для множества ключей в d будет так наверное:

```
var item = $('<div class="container-box"></div>');
item.text( Object.keys( d ).map( key => `${key} - ${d[key]}` ).join(' ') );
$('.wrapper').append( item );
```

Comment: Да это работает, но что делать если там более сложная разметка, всю эту разметку вставлять в js код? Или есть другой способ подгрузить этот ответ на типа $('.wrapper').load("http://slim.com/spirits/panel/post .container_box"); Только подгрузить добавленный пост и вставить в эту разметку более сложную разметку

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, налету вы не сможете никак использовать шаблонизатор от php. Поэтому в любом случае нужно писать JS, который преобразует объект в строку. Может не таким хардкодным способом как у меня в примере, а например проходом по свойствам объекта. Сейчас обновлю код выше.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду разбираться и пробовать без шаблонизатора